# i want operating multiple services with multiple domain and sub-domain

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, subdomain

i have one linux VM instance in google cloud platform.
and i have multiple domin. example aaa.com, bbb.com 
and i want multiple service and set sub-domains

```
service    port    subdomain
apache1    80      aa.aaa.com
apache2    81      bb.aaa.com
tomcat1    8080    cc.aaa.com
tomcat2    8081    dd.aaa.com
nodejs1    8000    ee.aaa.com
nodejs2    8001    ff.aaa.com
rshiny1    3838    aa.bbb.com
rshiny2    3839    bb.bbb.com
ftp1       21      cc.bbb.com
ftp2       20      dd.bbb.com
mariadb1   3306    ee.bbb.com
mariadb2   3307    ff.bbb.com
oracle1    1521    gg.bbb.com
oracle2    1522    hh.bbb.com
```

if i use only apache web server, i can setting sub-domain in virtual host.
but this is many services. how can i setting all sub-domains? 
in apache? node.js? dns?
please reply to my question.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what a reverse proxy is for. And it is fairly straightforward to configure Apache to do it.

Run a single Apache for the main front-end and have it serve the default http/https porst (80/443). Then use it to proxy vhost requests to individual services as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ServerName bb.aaa.com

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:81/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:81/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ServerName cc.aaa.com

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>    
</VirtualHost>

# ...
```

Create one for each service. This way your server will route depending on the domain name in the request instead of the TCP port number.

Of course, if you do this you cannot use the default ports (80/443) for your internal services as your front-end Apache needs it. But you can also use the Apache running the service on the default ports as your proxy server.

Basically you will end up with this kind of setup:

```
                                         ┌────────────┐
                                    ┌┄┄┄┄┤ apache2:81 │
                                    ┆    └────────────┘
                                    ┆    ┌──────────────┐
                                    ├┄┄┄┄┤ tomcat1:8080 │
           ┌───────────────────┐    ┆    └──────────────┘
internet┄┄┄┤front-end apache:80├┄┄┄┄┤    ┌──────────────┐
           └───────────────────┘    ├┄┄┄┄┤ tomcat2:8081 │
                                    ┆    └──────────────┘
                                    ┆
                                    .
                                    .
```

This type of setup is very flexible allowing you to implement things like load-balancing and routing services based on `<Location>` instead of domain name or port number. Before CORS, this was the standard way to implement microservices by using a single Apache or Nginx to route by location/url path.

Comment: thanks for your reply!! you mean Apache VirtualHost is answer. i will try this as soon as possible and share result.